# How to load data into couple of tables from a single files with different records structure in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a single file with a structure like:

```
A 1 2 3
A 4 5 6
A 5 8 12
B abc cde
B and fae
B bsd oio
C 1
C 2
C 3
```

and would like to load the data in 3 simple tables (A (int int int), B(string string) C(int)).

Is it possible and how?

It's also fine for me, if A(string int int int) etc. with the first column of the file to be included in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with option 1 as Praveen suggests.  I'd create an external table of only a string, and use the `FROM ( ... )` syntax to insert into multiple tables at once. I think something like the following would work

```
create external table source_table( line string )
stored as textfile
location '/myfile';

from ( select split( line , " ") as col_array from source_table ) cols
  insert overwrite table A select col_array[1], col_array[2], col_array[3] where col_array[0] = 'A'
  insert overwrite table B select col_array[1], col_array[2] where col_array[0] = 'B'
  insert overwrite table C select col_array[1] where col_array[0] = 'C';
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1) Map the entire data to a Hive table and then use the [insert overwrite table](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries) .... option to map the appropriate data to the target tables.

Option 2) Develop a MR program to split the file into multiple files and then do the mapping of the files to the target tables in Hive.

Comment: Thanks! 2 is not as I try to solve this without using MR or Pig or other pre-processing.